# Neural network training accuracy is too low and prediction is not working in Image Classification with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am following this guide to learn image classification with neural networks:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

And I implement this code for my custom dataset. I have 2300 gray scaled 1024x1024 pictures to train model. I hold all my images in 3D numpy array as train_images and test_images. I have 4 class which are 0,1,2,3 and I hold those as list, named "labels".

```
train_images.shape # returns (2300,1024,1024)
test_images.shape # returns (384,1024,1024)

# normalize values
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1024, 1024)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, labels, epochs=10)
```

Everything almost same with guide. But my epoch accuracy is around 0.4

```
Epoch 10/10
...
2176/2300 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.5701 - acc: 0.4062
2208/2300 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.5628 - acc: 0.4067
2240/2300 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.5485 - acc: 0.4076
2272/2300 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 9.5417 - acc: 0.4080
2300/2300 [==============================] - 12s 5ms/step - loss: 9.5307 - acc: 0.4087
```

Also in guide some predictions are fractional but when I try to do prediction, My model predictions are only 0 or 1. It says this is %100 (x) but its wrong.

```
predictions = model.predict(test_images)
print(predictions)
# 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
# 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
# 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

**UPDATED**

Here is epoch results for 256*256 2 classed 100 images per class:

```
32/200 [===>..........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 8.5627 - acc: 0.4688
200/200 [==============================] - 0s 317us/step - loss: 8.0590 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 10/10
```

Also I lowered my classes into 2 but my predictions are still return %100 and wrong class.

---

I dont know where I am doing wrong. If you have any advice/idea I would be grateful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

40% accuracy is not good. It needs to train more. You should rescale images to `128 or 256` to save time. Also try increasing epoch count to something like 100 or minimize loss to at least around 1 before testing. Another thing is class imbalance.

According to this, https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.07747 link `Fashion MNIST` contains `7000` images per class with `70000` images in total. If your dataset has class imbalance which seems likely then you should look into other metrics and methods.

Comment: Yes my classes are imbalance, I can balance that but the problem is (I think) every epoch's final accuracy stuck at 0.4. it is staying same not increasing over time. I feel that there is something wrong. And I would be happy if you give me example metric or methods that can fits my set.

Comment: Can you provide the result by using only 100 images per class and resize all images to 256*256. Also does your model have `convolution layers`? It does not seem like it. Looks like MLP with 128 hidden units 4 output units and no convolution. `That is the problem`. You should add `conv2d` layers before dense with pooling, dropout, batch normalization. You can check with, `VGG-like convnet` here, https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/.

Comment: Hello again, I updated my question. Also checking CNN model maybe as you told its happening because there is no convolution layers

Comment: Thank you again for your CNN advice. I have checked that but Im in trouble with it too :( When you have a time can you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953248/how-can-i-predict-single-image-in-keras-cnn-model