# How can I predict single image in Keras CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I am following this guide to learn image classification with CNN and I implemented this code into my data set:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

```
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)  # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)  # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_img_folder,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='categorical',
                                                           color_mode='grayscale')

val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=valid_img_folder,
                                                              target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                                              color_mode='grayscale'
                                                              )

model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train_value // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_steps=total_valid_value // batch_size
)

# Single prediction
img = []
temp = np.array(Image.open('path/to/pic.jpg').resize((256, 256), Image.ANTIALIAS))
temp.shape = temp.shape + (1,) # now its (256, 256, 1)
img.append(temp)
test = np.array(img) # (1, 1024, 1024, 1)
prediction = model.predict(test)
```

When I try predict_generator function:

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255.)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test_images/',
                                                  classes=['0', '1', '2'],
                                                  color_mode='grayscale',
                                                  shuffle=True,
                                                  # use same size as in training
                                                  target_size=(256, 256))

preds = model.predict_generator(test_generator, steps=4) # I dont know what is steps doing. I put there because of error.
```

My first question is: I can get training and validation accuracy but I want to get single picture's prediction result. How can I do that? Example:

```
foo = model.predict(path/to/pic.jpg)
# foo returns 0-> 0.70 | 1-> 0.30
```

Added: When I try to use model.predict like that I got this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1024, 1024)
```

or converting to 2d (and also 3d) np.array still got same.

**My second question is:** is there any way to predict without complete %100? I mean If we have 2 classes (cat and dog) and test moon picture I want to get results like that:

```
%15 cat | %10 dog
```

not

```
%50 cat | %50 dog
```

I tried to put garbage class as following changing. When I run that on`history = model.fit_generator` line I got following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First question :I can get training and validation accuracy but I want to get single picture's prediction result. How can I do that?

As you can see in [the doc](https://keras.io/models/model/), you can totally use `model.predict(x)`, as long as your `x` is :
- A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
- A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs.
- A generator or keras.utils.Sequence returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample weights).

You just have to write the code that reads the .jpg image and feed it to the model.

> Second question : is there any way to predict without complete %100? I mean If we have 2 classes (cat and dog) and test moon picture i want to get results like that:

You could create a third class 'garbage', to do so you'll need to change the last layer of your net to:

```py
Dense(3, activation='softmax')
```

And change your loss to `categorical_crossentropy`

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And change `class_mode` to `categorical` and not `binary`.

In that case you'll have dog:15%, cat:10%, garbage: 75%

Edit on conv2D error :

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (1024, 1024)

you have :

```py
Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3)),
```

This means that **an** image is `(height, width, channel)`.
 As seen in [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D), since this is the input_layer you need to provide the format in 4D with the shape : `(samples, rows, cols, channels)`. If you want to give only one image, you need to have an array shaped as `(1, rows, cols, channels)`.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. I tried to implement both advice but I got errors that added my question. If you dont mind can you check?

Comment: Yeah the error you get is because you now have a third class but it's not on your data, your data generator is then creating only 2 classes, what you could do is take some photos of everything and label them as 'garbage'

Comment: Oh I missed that thank you but still I got 4 dimension error which I mentioned above just before second question. My array is number of images and image resolution (1, 1024, 1024) but I dont know what I have to put as 4th dimension?

Comment: I added on my post your answer, but it's strange that you have only `1` as a channel and not `3` as you defined in your conv2D layer

Comment: I see now my problem is much clear. train_data_gen is generating my images with 3 channels but my images are gray-scaled. I changed my code into like yours and also added color_mode attribute to generator. Training and validation is working and when I tried to predict single image by predict() func (also shaped my array into (1, 1024, 1024, 1) it always predicts %100 to last class which is wrong) I feel Im doing wrong something but I couldnt figure out. May I kindly ask can you check again?

Comment: Alright, I don't have the answer out of the box. What I can say is that there is no need to `shuffle` in the test generator you better put it to False. Also, don't add the `classes` field and add `class_mode=None`. `step`argument is the total number of batches in your data (ie if you have 2000 images with a batch_size of 2 it should be `step=1000`

Comment: Its much clear now. Thank you for your all answers :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

> img.shape was (28,28,1)

I used following snipped to change it to (1,28,28,1) and it worked!

```
img = np.expand_dims(img,0)
result = cnn.predict(img)
```

finally get your output by:

```
result = result.round()
```